# Why is ${\varphi}^{-1} (A)$ closed in $V$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-writing, affine-varieties

Let $L$ be a field and $K$ be a subfield of $L.$ Let $V$ be an affine algebraic $K$-variety in $\Bbb A^n (L).$ Then the coordinate ring $K[V]$ is defined by

$$K[V] = \frac {K[X_1,X_2, \dots ,X_n]} {\mathcal I(V)}$$

where $\mathcal I(V)$ is the vanishing ideal of $V.$ Now for any $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n) \in V$ set $p_x = \mathcal I_V \left ( \{(x_1,x_2, \dots,x_n) \} \right)$ the set of all functions $\psi \in K[V]$ such that $\psi (x_1,x_2, \dots, x_n) = 0.$ Then $p_x$ is a prime ideal $\ne K[V]$.

We thus have a mapping $\varphi : V \longrightarrow \mathrm {Spec} (K[V])$ defined by $x \mapsto p_x.$ In my book it has been claimed that $\varphi$ is continuous. In order to see it I take a closed subset $A$ of $\mathrm {Spec} (K[V]).$ Then $\exists$ an ideal $I$ of $K[V]$ such that $A=V(I)=\{p \in \mathrm {Spec} (K[V]) : p \supseteq I \},$ the zero set of the ideal $I$ in $\mathrm {Spec} (K[V]).$ Then

$$\begin{align} {\varphi}^{-1} (A) & = \{x \in V : \varphi (x) \in A \}.\\ & = \{x \in V : p_x \in A \}.\\ & = \{x \in V:p_x \supseteq I\}. \end{align}$$

But I don't understand why is the set $\{x \in V:p_x \supseteq I\}$ closed in $V.$ Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What do u mean by a $K$-varitey in $\mathbb A^n(L)$ ?

Comment: A $K$-variety $V$ in $\Bbb A^n (L)$ is the common solutions of finitely many system of polynomials over $K$ in $n$ variables let's say $X_1,X_2, \cdots , X_n.$

Comment: What is the topology?

Comment: The closed sets of a variety $V$ looks like $V (S) = \{(x_1,x_2, \cdots , x_n) \in V : f(x_1,x_2, \cdots , x_n) = 0\ \text {for all}\ f \in S \}$ where $S \subseteq K[X_1,X_2, \cdots , X_n]$ is a set of some polynomials in $n$ variables $X_1,X_2, \cdots ,X_n$ over $K.$ This defines a topology on $V.$

Comment: How do you guarantee @reuns that all the prime ideals $p$ of $K[V]$ is of the form $p_x$ for some $x = (x_1,x_2 , \cdots , x_n) \in V$?

Comment: Here it is not a metric space so continuous is that $\varphi^{-1}(U)$ is open for $U$ open ie. for some ideal $I$ of $K[V]$, $U = \{ p \in Spec(K[V]), p \not \subset I\}$ so that $\varphi^{-1}(U) = \{ y \in V, p_y \not \in U\} = V- Z(I)$ where $Z(I) = \{ y \in V, \forall f \in I, f(y)=0\}$ is closed so $V-Z(I)$ is open. When restricted to the maximal ideals $\varphi^{-1}$ is a topological isomorphism

Answer (score 1):

$\{x\in V : p_x \supset I \} = \mathscr V(I)$ since $I\subset p_x \iff x\in \mathscr V(I)$ where if $J$ is an ideal of $K[V]$ then define $\mathscr V(J)= \{p \in V : f(p)= 0 \forall f \in K[V] \}$

Note: This is well defined since elements of $K[V]$ give distinct functions on $V$.

Comment: What is $\mathscr {V} (I)$ here?

Comment: If $I$ is an ideal of $K[X_1,..,X_n]$ ( note it is finitely generated by noetherian condition) then $\mathscr V(I) =\{p \in \mathbb A^n(L) : f(p)=0 \forall f \in I \} $

Comment: But in your answer $I$ is not an ideal of $K[X_1,X_2, \cdots , X_n]$; rather it is an ideal of $K[V] = \frac {K[X_1,X_2, \cdots , X_n] } {\mathcal {I} (V)}.$ Do you use correspondence theorem here? Instead of thinking $I$ as an ideal of $K[V]$ are you considering it as an ideal of $K[X_1,X_2 , \cdots , X_n]$ containing $\mathcal {I} (V)$?

Comment: Okay editing. The idea is the same since basically as functions u arent adding anything substantial.

Comment: Also in ur definition of the topology u should add $S\supset \mathcal I(V)$

Comment: You are confusing me a lot. What is $I + \mathcal {I} (V)$? $I$ is an ideal of $K[V]$ but $\mathcal {I} (V)$ is an ideal of $K[X_1,X_2, \cdots , X_n].$ How do you add them? I know addition of two ideals in a ring. But in your answer you have added two ideals of two different rings. How does $I + \mathcal {I} (V)$ look like? Try to give a crystal clear answer. Otherwise please don't give an incomplete answer.